# Devexpress XAF - How Insert record of detail in other class

Tags: devexpress, xaf

Look at the situation:
Having 4 classes as follows description below, how could I when choosing a Task in OrderService automatically include CheckLists (detail) connected to this Task in OrderCheckList?

OrderService
(1 to 1 relationship with Tasks)
(1-to-many relationship with CheckListsOrder)

Tasks
(1-to-many relationship with checklists)

CheckLists

OrderCheckLists

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include detail editor you can use [EditorAlias(EditorAliases.DetailPropertyEditor)] attribute, but if I am not mistaken this would only work for 1-1 relationships (i might be wrong - check in the documentation)

Also worth looking at is this attribute:
[ExpandObjectMembersAttribute(ExpandObjectMembers.Never)]

Hope this at least points you in a right direction.