# Disabled fields when including detail editor

Tags: c#, .net, xaf

I looked for the answer of the problem in the following link and I have tried it:
[Devexpress XAF - How Insert record of detail in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957410/devexpress-xaf-how-insert-record-of-detail-in-other-class)

Let's say we have class A, and we want to expand all fields of class B inside class A form -using the two given attributes as given solutions mentioned in the attached link-. class A has a foreign key that holds class's B primary key, while class B has not (one-to-one relation).
if we are creating new object from class A, the result was as following: All fields from class B are displayed in class A form, but they are disabled; we cannot fill them.

Why are the fields disabled and how to fix this problem so I can fill and edit these fields. The result I need is the ability to create object B inside and through the creation of object A.